# Is a question about git wrapping scripting adequate in this forum?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is this question better/well-places in SE?

"maybe it could be beneficial to have shortcuts similar to virtual environmentwrapper vs venv for standard activities with git which could be time saving as opposite to typing many commands."? i.e. whether it's empiricially provable to save time beyond matter of taste. - With examples.

Askes so far in [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270197/fast-git-change-sets-with-git-wrapping-scripts).

Comment: From this post, I don't get which question you want to ask here. Surely not the same one you asked on Codereview, since I guess you already know that [crossposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) are not accepted by the community.

Comment: Hi - Crosspost would mean I leave it in both places. I was not sure regarding moving the question here if it would be a better place.

Answer (score 5):

No, [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270197/fast-git-change-sets-with-git-wrapping-scripts) would most likely be downvoted, closed, and deleted here on this site.

I can spot four "real" questions in that post (the last four bullet points). These questions are, however, about things which are in need of a requirements analysis (your own personal requirements, the kind of requirements only you know), or some opinionated "matter-of-taste" decisions. These kind of questions are regularly closed here on this site, with one of the three predefined close reasons

- too opinionated
- needs more focus
- needs details or clarity

I think what could help you here is a discussion of these topics, but the SE sites don't want to be discussion sites. The only place in the SE network where  discussions are allowed are the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), maybe the chat room of this site ("[The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)"). However, there is no guarantee to find a suitable discussion partner there, you may need some luck for this.